# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

```
 df.withColumn(x, when($"x" > 75, $"x" + 10).otherwise($"x")).show()
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`x`' given input columns: [Name, Subject, Marks];;
'Project [Name#7, Subject#8, CASE WHEN ('x > 75) THEN ('x + 10) ELSE 'x END AS Marks#38]

scala> df.show()
+----+-------+-----+
|Name|Subject|Marks|
+----+-------+-----+
| Ram|Physics|   80|
|Sham|English|   90|
|Ayan|   Math|   70|
+----+-------+-----+


scala> x
res6: String = Marks
```

I want to pass a variable as a parameter and which stores a column value of the dataframe. And based on that parameter it will check condition, calculate value and replace a column with a same name in that dataframe.

Actually the bigger problem is, there is multiple columns in same name like "col1","col2","col3".... I will store this columns in a array and iterate over the array by passing the value of the array in dataframe operation. But as of now. Please let me know the solution of the problem if it can be handeled in spark-scala.

Comment: Shall we close the thread by [accepting the answer as owner?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369717)

Comment: I have added solution, Can you check & let me know if its not working.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better understanding I have separated columns as `requiredColumns` & `allColumns`.

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----+-------+-----+
|Name|Subject|Marks|
+----+-------+-----+
|Ram |Physics|80   |
|Sham|English|90   |
|Ayan|Math   |70   |
+----+-------+-----+
```

```
scala> val requiredColumns = Set("Marks")
requiredColumns: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(Marks)
```

```
scala> val allColumns = df.columns
allColumns: Array[String] = Array(Name, Subject, Marks)
```

```
scala> 
val columnExpr =  allColumns
                    .filterNot(requiredColumn(_))
                    .map(col(_)) ++ requiredColumns
                    .map(c => when(col(c) > 75,col(c) + 10).otherwise(col(c)).as(c))
```

**Output**

```
scala> df.select(columnExpr:_*).show(false)
+----+-------+-----+
|Name|Subject|Marks|
+----+-------+-----+
|Ram |Physics|90   |
|Sham|English|100  |
|Ayan|Math   |70   |
+----+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with **[String interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)** **`col({s"${x}"})`**.

**`Example:`**

```
val df=Seq(("Ram","Physics",80),("Sham","English",90),("Ayan","Math",70)).toDF("Name","Subject","Marks")

df.show()
//+----+-------+-----+
//|Name|Subject|Marks|
//+----+-------+-----+
//| Ram|Physics|   80|
//|Sham|English|   90|
//|Ayan|   Math|   70|
//+----+-------+-----+

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val x:String = "Marks"

df.withColumn(x, when(col(s"${x}") > 75, col(s"${x}") + 10).otherwise(col(s"${x}"))).show()
//+----+-------+-----+
//|Name|Subject|Marks|
//+----+-------+-----+
//| Ram|Physics|   90|
//|Sham|English|  100|
//|Ayan|   Math|   70|
//+----+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Shall we close the thread by [accepting the answer as owner?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369717)

Comment: @Shu, in which spark version it is working since I am using DBR 6.5, Spark 2.4.5 and is not working.

error: not found: value x
df.withColumn(x, when(col(s"${x}") > 75, col(s"${x}") + 10).otherwise(col(s"${x}"))).show()

Comment: @sathiyarajan, I have missed defining `variable x` while copying `val x:String = "Marks"` and updated the answer.. Please check now..!

Comment: @Shu, We don't need string interpolation inside `col`. We can directly use the variable defined as string inside `functions.col`. Please check my answer

Comment: @Shu , thanks. Just want to know one more thing if you have a solution. If we want iterate over columns , then everytime we have to define a new dataframe as dataframe is immutable. Is there any way to declare array of dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Use `functions.col` as below-

```scala
 df1.show(false)

    /**
      * +----+-------+-----+
      * |Name|Subject|Marks|
      * +----+-------+-----+
      * |Ram |Physics|80   |
      * |Sham|English|90   |
      * |Ayan|Math   |70   |
      * +----+-------+-----+
*/
val x = "Marks"
    // use functions.col
    df1.withColumn(x, when(col(x) > 75, col(x) + 10).otherwise(col(x)))
      .show()

    /**
      * +----+-------+-----+
      * |Name|Subject|Marks|
      * +----+-------+-----+
      * | Ram|Physics|   90|
      * |Sham|English|  100|
      * |Ayan|   Math|   70|
      * +----+-------+-----+
      */
```

Comment: thanks. Just want to know one more thing if you have a solution. If we want iterate over columns , then everytime we have to define a new dataframe as dataframe is immutable. Is there any way to declare array of dataframe.

Comment: Not sure if i get you correctly. you can always do that. but wanted to know the intention. I would suggest to raise new follow up query with sample i/p and o/p. with the proper description of the problem